# How to exclude cpp files from project in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, file, project

I want to exclude a cpp file with main function from a qt project and run the project with another cpp file with main function in it. But when I remove (not Delete) cpp file, I encounter a linker error cause there is 2 main functions in my project. One in the removed cpp file and one in the cpp file I want to compile and run.

How can I implement excluding a file from project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first do a Clean Project (to remove the old `.obj` files from the build folder)

then in your .pro file there is a section `SOURCES` just remove the filename from there and rerun qmake

Comment: That removes the files from the project entirely, and doesn't actually "exclude" the files